# Find the minimum absolute value between 2 elements of an array with minimum complexity

Tags: algorithm, go

My goal is to find the minimum absolute value between 2 elements of an array, in the example below the min absolute value is beetwen 1 and 4 and the result is 3

Here is my implementation of the solution:

```
    input := [6]int{8,1,13,30,4,20} 
    minAbsVal := math.MaxFloat64 
    
    for i := 0; i < len(input); i++ {
        for j := i+1; j < len(input); j++ {
                if math.Abs(float64(input[i] - input[j])) < minAbsVal {
            minAbsVal = math.Abs(float64(input[i] - input[j]))
            }
        }
    }
    
    fmt.Println("Result", minAbsVal)
```

You can find the implémetation here : https://play.golang.org/p/D2DGy7YcVSv

I want to know if there is a solution with less complexity ?

Comment: What is "less complexity"? Shorter code?

Comment: @icza I believe he means computational complexity.

Comment: Indeed, I referred to computational complexity

Comment: If the maximum element present in the array does not exceed the size of the array, then you can use `counting sort` which will sort your array in `O(n)` where n is the size of the array. In the sorted array, you can easily find the minimum absolute value between 2 elements of the array. Here is a link on counting sort, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/

Comment: Thanks I will look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You algorithm is currently `O(n^2)`.

When sorted, smallest absolute difference must be between 2 sequential elements.

You can sort integers in `O(n log n)`, with quick sort, merge sort etc. , and after having it sorted, you could have a final step with `O(n)`

There might be a better implementation with dynamic programming, maybe a single sorting algorithm where you also find the smallest difference, however, this is what I thought

```
    
    sortedArray = sorted(array) // implement a sorted function
    n := sortedArray[len(sortedArray) - 1)]
    minDif := 2^32 // chose a better initial value like infinity
  
    for i := range n-1 {
        if sortedArray[i+1] - sortedArray[i] < minDif{
           minDif = sortedArray[i + 1] - sortedArray[i]
        }
    }

   
    return minDif
```

Comment: I did consider counter sort and heap but i find your solution more simple because I can use directly the sort in go, here the functional implementation : https://play.golang.org/p/f4OyLWh4so-

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a Heap, it sorts itself:

```
package main

import (
   "container/heap"
   "sort"
)

type slice struct { sort.IntSlice }
func (s slice) Pop() interface{} { return 0 }
func (s slice) Push(x interface{}) {}

func main() {
   s := slice{
      sort.IntSlice{8, 1, 13, 30, 4, 20},
   }
   heap.Init(s)
   println("Result", s.IntSlice[0])
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/container/heap